# DataView Filtering ONLY when Changing the Filter

Tags: slickgrid

**We only want the filtering to be fired only when manipulating the filter, not when editing data.**

We are using slickgrid for extensive data entry.  One challenge we are having is that we would like to be able to use the filtering as intended, but then also be able to add additional rows that may not match the filter, while also leaving the filter applied. Before we tear apart the code, I thought we should post the question....

Is there some option we are missing to do this, or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of this usecase, but it hasn't been addressed by the DataView yet.  The right solution is to make running the filter pass a manual step in the DataView, which would also speed up other operations without the need to specify refresh hints.

On my TODO list, but I can't tell you when I'll get around to it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around (until this feature is implemented in SlickGrid, as per Tin's post), you can add an extra value to new rows, flagging them as newly-added. (Don't add a column for this value.) Then change your filters to return true if the flag is set before checking the filter requirements. When the user changes the filter, update the data to remove the flag from any row that has it. Not ideal but I think it's the best you can do right now.